# Finding same objects in Java

Tags: java, object, hash, equality

I produce a bunch of objects in Java. Each object has attribute area and a set of integers. I want to store those objects for example in a map(keys should be integers in a growing order). Two objects are the same if their area is equal and their sets are the same.

If two objects don't have the same area then there is no need for me to check whether their sets are the same.

What is the best practice for implementing this in Java? How should I compose hash and equal functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's sample pair of `hashCode\equals` generated by IDE:

```
class Sample  {
    final int area;
    final Set<Integer> someData;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Sample sample = (Sample) o;

        if (area != sample.area) return false;
        if (!someData.equals(sample.someData)) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = area;
        result = 31 * result + someData.hashCode();
        return result;
    }
}
```

This code assumes `someData` can't be null -- to simplify things. You can see that equality of types is checked at first, then `area` equality is checked and then equality of `Set<Integer>` is checked. Note that built-in `equals` of `Set` is used in this -- so you have re-usage of that method. This is idiomatic way to test compound types for equality.

Answer (score 1):

You just need your object to implement the `Comparable` [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and code your logic in the `compareTo` method. Here's a good [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) to help you achieve that.

Comment: This needed only if you going to sort objects. If you just need to have dictionary of such objects, you need just proper `hashCode()` and `equals()`

Answer (score 1):

Just compare their area first in `equals` (after the `==` and type check of course), and return `false` if these differ. If the areas equal, go on and compare the sets.

For implementing `equals` (and `hashCode`) in general, here is [a relevant thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java) and [a good article](http://www.billthelizard.blogspot.com/2008/08/implementing-equals-in-java.html) (including several further references).

Answer (score 1):

A rule of thumb is that you should compare all relevant fields in your `equals()` implementation (fastest first, so compare your `area`s up front, then the integer sets) and use THE SAME fields in your `hashCode()`. If in doubt, use Eclipse's `Source - Generate hashCode() and equals()...` feature (and then fix the `equals()` code to compare the `area`s first.)